# Easy way to increment cell numbers in Excel

Tags: c#, excel, ms-office

I'm an intermediate C# programmer, but I'm just starting out with Office automation, specifically Excel for now. I've got to say, the Office API is lacking, or at least it forces you to think about problems differently. One thing that's driving me nuts is cell numbers, such as `A1` and `B5` and so on. I'm forced to manipulate them often, but there's no easy way to do this. For example, if I'm on column C7 and want to copy or move something to B7, I can't just use `--C7`. Instead I have to figure out the numerical value of `C`, decrement it, turn it back into a letter then concatenate it with the row number again.

I could write methods to do this myself (e.g. `decrementColumn()`, `decrementRow()`, `addColumns( String currentCellName, int howManyToAdd)` ), but I don't want to reinvent the wheel. Does a library of functions exist for such oft-needed conversions or am I going to have to roll my own?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To copy/move values easily, you can use the `.Offset` method, which returns a Range.

For example, if the range/cell you are working with is `C7`, where `rng` represents this Range object:

`rng.Offset(0,-1).Value = rng.Value`

This returns the range, offset by -1 colums.

`rng.Offset(10,15)` would return a cell/range 10 rows below, and 15 columns right, etc.

You may also look at `R1C1` address style in Excel, although I have never been fond of that. This link for Excel 2007 but should be mostly appropriate for any version of Excel.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee264226(v=office.12).aspx

Comment: Thanks, this will help a lot!

Comment: Also, you can always refer to a range by its cell location, e.g., `Sheets(1).Cells(1,1)` is equivalent to `Sheets(1).Range("A1")`, and `.Cells(109,13)` is equivalent to `.Range("M109")`, etc.  That's probably messier than using the `.Offset` method, but it's at least another option for you to explore.